# Как лучше объединить один коммит в ветку?

Tags: git

Есть три ветки `master`, `dev1`, `dev2`. Заказчик хочет что бы я взял один коммит из `dev1` и слил его с `dev2`, сделал некоторые правки, и далее эти обе ветки ветки будут слиты в мастер. Он хочет что бы я просто скопипастил код из коммита, но я никак не могу ужиться с мыслю что это не лучший вариант.

Слить всю ветку я не могу, так хочет заказчик. Как я понимаю chery-pick не могу использовать, так как он перенесет коммит а мне этого не нужно.

Есть ли вариант слить только один коммит с веткой при этом сохранить историю, и далее корректно слить обе ветки в мастер? (Конечным сливанием веток буду заниматься не я, это будет еще той проблемой)
Или я что то упускаю?

Comment: chery-pick вполне делает то, что вам надо. "Переноса" коммита как такового не существует, это будет самостоятельный коммит.

Comment: `cherry-pick` не перенесет, а скопирует коммит (точнее, создаст ещё один почти такой же). То есть в ветке-источнике этот коммит останется.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо стоит поиграться отдельно, что бы правильно понять принцип работы.

Comment: @Toxa вот вам тренажер https://learngitbranching.js.org/ (только там сегодня, похоже, сертификат слетел).

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо, действительно будет полезно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, прикольная песочница! сделал закладку, буду пропагандировать.